# The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large when sending big POST request from web server to IIS backend

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, curl, iis-8

My story is we have three clients (android/ios/web) use a Restful Microsoft backend with a suite API.

There is an upload image api which android/ios apps upload big images successfully but from our web server(PHP/CodeIgniter) can't not upload big images with their server.
When we send small image less than 30KB, the POST request is successful but with larger image the POST request is always return "The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large." and error code 413.

Below is my upload function:

```
/**
     * This function will post an image to Social Plus
     * 1. Copy image, which is sent from user's browser, to "upload_path" directory
     * 2. Read content of "image file" and insert into body of POST's request
     * 3. Send a POST request of binary to SS+ via Curl library
     * 4. Return blobHandle and file's info back to browser
     */
    function img_upload(){
        $data = array();
        $config['upload_path']          = './assets/upload_files/'; //location of image file
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpeg|png|gif|jpg';
        $config['encrypt_name']         = true; //convert normal name file to encrypted file name
        $config['max_size']             = 104857600; //1000MB
        $session_token = $this->input->post("session_token");
        $authorization = "Bearer " . $session_token;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo json_encode($error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            //Reading content binary of image
            $raw_data = file_get_contents($data['full_path']);
            $headers = array('Authorization: '.$authorization,'Content-Type: '.$data['file_type'],
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($raw_data));
            $image_data = array(
                'image' => base64_encode($raw_data)
            );



            $curl = curl_init ();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,0);
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, BASE_SOCIAL_PLUS_USER_PHOTO_URL);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_VERBOSE , 0 );
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$raw_data);
            $photo_details = curl_exec($curl);
            $photo=json_decode($photo_details,true);

            $datestring = '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s:%u %a';
            $time = time();

            if(curl_errno($curl))
            {
                echo 'error:xxx' . curl_error($curl);
            }
            curl_close ( $curl );

            if(!isset($photo['blobHandle']))
            {
                $error = array('error' =>"Oop...Failed to upload image!");
                unlink($data['full_path']);
                $error["time_stamp"] = mdate($datestring, $time);
                $error["api_return"] = $photo_details;
                echo json_encode($error);
            } else {
                $photo_handle=$photo['blobHandle'];
                $data['blob_Handle'] = $photo_handle;
                $data["time_stamp"] = mdate($datestring, $time);
                $data["api_return"] = $photo;
                unlink($data['full_path']); //Delete uploaded file
                echo json_encode(
                    array("file_name"=>$data['orig_name'],
                        "file_size"=>round($data['file_size']),
                        "blob_handle"=>$photo_handle,
                        "file_type" => $data["file_type"],
                        "time_stamp" => $data['time_stamp'],
                        "api_return" => $data['api_return']));
            }
        }
    }
```

The Microsoft guys don't think it is their backend error. 
I had used WireShark to capture all package from Android and my local webserver. But there are similar package are sending out. As of now, we know there is limit of POST body request from IIS 8.5 which make IOS/Android app can send POST big image request base on HTTP library on each platform.

I also try to use CURL command to send a POST request by option -T (data file) but it doesn't help.

From WireShark result, there is a Encrypted Alert package sent from my web server to ISS backend and after that connection is drop immediately. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDRhv.png)

We tried to fix this issuse for a week but it doesn't help.:((

Comment: I just want to add a quick updates. The root cause is IIS backend have problem. If you get this kind of problem, then IIS backend people must be in charge of issue.